# OS X Server with SMTP Relay

Tags: smtp, osx-server, emailrelay, postfix-mta

Postfix lives in 2 locations on OS X / OS X Server

OSX Server / Mail tip -

Postfix location: /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/main.cf

Note: [smtp.gmail.com]:587 will break the UI I suspect due to the [].

Postfix sasl password:

/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/sasl/passwd

Don't forget to postmap update:

sudo postmap /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/sasl/passwd

There is also a /etc/postfix location which is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem. This helped me - 
main.cf

```
myhostname = smtp.gmail.com
# Use Gmail SMTP
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

and

sasl_passwd

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 email@gmail.com:pass
```

Comment: Had similar settings.  I went to the machine that worked with OS X Server Mail Enabled and the Relay checkbox checked.  The address field was blank.  When I populated it with smtp.gmail.com it started to fail just like my new El Capitan Server.  I don't know where that value is stored but I suspect its in a plist file somewhere and with SIP enabled I will have to disable that to fix and try again.  I have a feeling using OS X Mail + Postfix is causing the issue and I had some magic combination that worked on my older Mavericks build.

Answer (score 0):

### Postfix lives in 2 locations on OS X / OS X Server

OSX Server / Mail tip -

Postfix location:
`/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/main.cf`

Note: [smtp.gmail.com]:587 will break the UI I suspect due to the [].

Postfix sasl password:

`/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/sasl/passwd`

Don't  forget to postmap update:

`sudo postmap /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/sasl/passwd`

There is also a `/etc/postfix` location which is confusing.

Added above setting from Viktar to the main.cf and its down the road now.